# javascript format error

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, slider

```
 var liHtml = "<div class='slide'><a href='"+itemLink+"' target='_blank' border='0'><img width='420' height='220'  src='" + imageLink +"'/></a>" + "<div class="caption" style="bottom:'0'"><p>" + title + "</p></div></div>";
```

firebug gives me this error

```
missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error] var liHtml = "<div class='slide'><...'"><p>" + title + "</p></div></div>";
```

what am i missing. The above code should look like below

```
<div class="slide">
                        <a href="photos/jliba/4665625073/" title="145.365 - Happy Bokeh Thursday" target="_blank"><img src="img/slide-1.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 1"></a>
                        <div class="caption" style="bottom:0">
                            <p>Happy Bokeh Thursday!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: As well as the quoting problem, you also have potential cross-site-scripting security vulnerabilities if any of the strings you're dumping into HTML without escaping them are user-submitted. Using DOM methods instead of HTML-hacking avoids the problem of having to HTML-escape your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

`"<div class="caption" style="bottom:'0'"><p>"`  in your concatenation

with

```
"<div class=\"caption\" style=\"bottom:'0'\"><p>"
```

i.e:

```
var liHtml = "<div class='slide'><a href='"+itemLink+"' target='_blank' border='0'><img width='420' height='220'  src='" + imageLink +"'/></a>" + "<div class=\"caption\" style=\"bottom:'0'\"><p>" + title + "</p></div></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote mismatch in the string at the point `<div class="caption" style="bottom:'0'"><p>`. Escaping or using a single quote instead will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your double quotes.  Example:

Replace:

```
 .. + "<div class="caption" style="bottom:'0'"><p>" + ..
```

With:

```
..  + "<div class=\"caption\" style=\"bottom:'0'\"><p>" + ..
```